# Graph with nodes in a dictionary, distances in nested dictionary and shortest distance in another nested dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm, nodes, graph-theory

I am looking at the following tutorial (http://tryalgo.org/en/graphs/2018/04/06/graphs_in_python/) and have made the `G` dictionary. I am now trying to make the `weights` dictionary that the author talks about, but doesn't actually do. Could anyone confirm whether I have done it correctly. By the way, the weights are random.

```
G = { "Alice":  ["Bob", "Claire", "Frank"],
      "Bob":    ["Alice"],
      "Claire": ["Alice", "Dennis", "Esther", "Frank"],
      "Dennis": ["Claire", "Esther", "George"],
      "Esther": ["Claire", "Dennis"],
      "Frank":  ["Alice", "Claire", "George"],
      "George": ["Dennis", "Frank"]}

w = {G["Alice"][0]:3, G["Alice"][1]:4, G["Alice"][2]:2,
     G["Bob"][0]:3,
     G["Claire"][0]:3, G["Claire"][1]:3, G["Claire"][2]:3, G["Claire"[3]:3,
     G["Dennis"][0]:3, G["Dennis"][1]:3, G["Dennis"][2]:3,
     G["Esther"][0]:3, G["Esther"][1]:3,
     G["Frank"][0]:3, G["Frank"][1]:3, G["Frank"][2]:3,
     G["George"][0]:3, G["George"][1]:3}
```

Furthermore, I am making a dictionary called shortest_distance which hold the shortest distance between each node, and all the other nodes.

```
shortest_distance = {"Alice":{"Bob":5, "Claire":2, "Frank":4},
        "Bob":{"Alice":3}, 
        .
        .
        "George":{"Dennis":2, "Frank":4}}
```

To give some context, this is going to be used in an algorithm to calculate sharply value. I kind of understand the algorithm, but I am not certain about how the data should be stored.

Answer (score 0):

To create the graph `G` by translating each name to an integer, you can iterate over the structure to create a mapping of each name to a current count. Then, the dictionary can be looped over and then the numerical value for each name can be looked up in the previous structure:

```
mapping = {a:i for i, a in enumerate(G)}
_G = [[mapping[c] for c in i] for i in G.values()]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 5], 
 [0], 
 [0, 3, 4, 5], 
 [2, 4, 6], 
 [2, 3], 
 [0, 2, 6], 
 [3, 5]]
```

---

Note that the correct listing for the output will only be obtained when the original structure `G` is ordered, which for dictionaries can only be achieved with Python 3.6 and onwards. If you are using a version of Python less than 3.6, consider utilizing a `collections.OrderedDict` or nested lists.

Answer (score 0):

> Edge weights need to be stored in a separate structure such that weight[v][u] is the weight of the edge (v,u). Such a structure would simply be a dictionary of dictionaries.

Your weights dictionary `W` is not a dictionary of dictionaries. It's a simple dictionary in which you keep overwriting values: `{'Alice':5, 'Bob': 3, 'Alice':1, 'Charlie':1}`.
`W['Alice']['Bob']` should return the weight of the edge from Alice to Bob, so W must have a key `'Alice'` which maps to a dictionary that has a `'Bob'` key which maps to the weight of the edge:
`W = {'Alice': {G["Alice"][0]:3}` or just `W = {'Alice':{'Bob':3}}`

Comment: Thanks! I assume that I would use the same method for my shortest_distance dictionary, except the values would be replaced by the shortest value between "Alice" and all the different nodes "Esther", "Bob" etc? I am actually trying to implement Algorithm 4 (page 51) in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.01764.pdf.

Comment: Yes, the structure of `shortest_distance` dict will be the same, just with the shortest distances instead of edge weights. Never heard of shapley value, but it sounds interesting and the algorithm doesn't look that bad (whereas my brain melts when looking at the formula below it) if you have Dijkstra's algorithm and the 'worthiness' function `f` already implemented.